# Asynchronous PureMVC in Python

Tags: python, model-view-controller, asynchronous, puremvc

Taking the following code from [here](http://www.andypatterns.com/index.php/blog/puremvc_minimal_wxpython/), from the shortened version at the bottom, exists this proxy:

```
class DataModelProxy(puremvc.patterns.proxy.Proxy):
    NAME = "DataModelProxy"

    def __init__(self):
        super(DataModelProxy, self).__init__(DataModelProxy.NAME, [])
        self.realdata = Data()
        self.sendNotification(AppFacade.DATA_CHANGED, self.realdata.data)

    def setData(self, data):
        self.realdata.data = data
        print "setData (model) to", data
        self.sendNotification(AppFacade.DATA_CHANGED, self.realdata.data)
```

Quoting from [here](http://puremvc.org/pages/docs/Python/docs/) from the PureMVC Python docs, it says:

> A Proxy might simply manage a reference to a local data object, in which case interacting with it might involve setting and getting of its data in synchronous fashion.
>
> Proxy classes are also used to encapsulate the application's interaction with remote services to save or retrieve data, in which case, we adopt an asyncronous idiom; setting data (or calling a method) on the Proxy and listening for a Notification to be sent when the Proxy has retrieved the data from the service.

If this is the case, how can I get my proxy to perfrom asynchronously when I have expensive and time consuming data to retreive?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really interesting. I just studied PureMVC and it is just my thought, not proven.

How about making use of Notifier in puremvc.patterns.observer? Or much easier way, in your asynchronous data-retrieving function, send a notification when the process is done :) That way sounds much PureMVC-way: communication by notifications. The only concern I guess is to make sure the notification mechanism is thread-safe.

One more idea. You can try the idea behind [Utility - AS3 / Startup Manager](http://trac.puremvc.org/Utility_AS3_StartupManager).